# php - how to pass variable value from function to add action

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, hook

I have funcition which is executed in plugin admin and function which is executed also from plugin but on cart with add action.

I want to:

pass bool parameter from plugin function to add action function.

Scenario is:

if variable condition is true in plugin function pass this value to add action cart function and if true don't execute add action function:

Example code:

```
function plugnFunction($varToPass) {

  $varToPass = false;

  if (condition is true) {
    $varToPass = true;
  } else { 
    $varToPass = false;
  }

}


add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', function () use ($varToPass) {

  if ($varToPass == true) {
    return;
  }

  //else start cart function 
});
```

But don't know how get value (true or false) from pluginFunction to cart function.

Thanks for help,

Comment: Not sure if `use ($varToPass)` will actually work in this context. And even if it does, a variable named `$varToPass` would then need to exist in the scope of where this action actually gets executed. This question could do with a bit more context, explaining what kind of condition you need to check there. Maybe your plugin method could be made into a static one, so that your function could just call it directly. Or the function could perhaps be implemented as a method of your plugin, so that it has access to the class properties ...

Comment: is about validation: if some fields have error then $varToPass is true and next hook with function will not execute. This I made because of avoiding js validation and possible php errors on cart